# How to match by lookup items with limit and skip in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have 2 collections as users and user_courses. user_courses collection is a many to many connection table. I need to filter users by registered course with pagination.

users collection looks like:

```
[
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("123"),
        "name": "Lorem Ipsum",
        "email": "lorem@ipsum.com"
    },
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("234"),
        "name": "Lorem Ipsum",
        "email": "lorem@ipsum.com"
    },
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("345"),
        "name": "Lorem Ipsum",
        "email": "lorem@ipsum.com"
    },
    ...
]
```

and user_course collection looks like:

```
[
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("12345"),
        "userId": ObjectId("123"),
        "courseId": ObjectId("111"),
    },
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("23456"),
        "userId": ObjectId("123"),
        "courseId": ObjectId("222"),
    },
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("34567"),
        "userId": ObjectId("123"),
        "courseId": ObjectId("333"),
    },
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("45678"),
        "userId": ObjectId("234"),
        "courseId": ObjectId("222"),
    },
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("56789"),
        "userId": ObjectId("345"),
        "courseId": ObjectId("111"),
    },
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("67890"),
        "userId": ObjectId("345"),
        "courseId": ObjectId("222"),
    },
    ...
]
```

And here's my code:

```
const filterObj = {
    "$or": [
        {
            "name": {
                $regex: searchKey
            }
        },
        {
            "email": {
                $regex: searchKey
            }
        }
    ]
}

Users.aggregate([
    { $match: filterObj },
    { $sort: { createdAt: -1 } },
    { $skip: skip },
    { $limit: limit },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'user_courses',
            localField: '_id',
            foreignField: 'userId',
            as: 'userCourses',
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: {
                            $and: [
                                {
                                    $eq: [
                                        "$courseId",
                                        new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(courseId)
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$userCourses"
    }
])
```

With this code, it gets first 10 items (limit: 10 and skip: 0) and then filters the result with match in pipeline. If i remove unwind option, it just applies filter inside lookup values and returns all users even if userCourses lookup is empty.

How can i filter users by registered course before sort, skip and limit?

Comment: you are treating mongo as a relationship database. https://www.mongodb.com/document-databases

Comment: I know it's wrong way to use mongo but database was designed by someone else. I'm making updates upon my customer's requests. There's have bigger problems inside but i cant fix 'em all with customer's budget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to apply the `$skip` and `$limit` after the `$lookup`:

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {$match: filterObj},
  {$sort: {createdAt: -1}},
  {$lookup: {
      from: "user_courses",
      as: "userCourses",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "userId",
      pipeline: [
        {$match: {"courseId": new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(courseId)}}
      ]
  }},
  {$match: {"userCourses.0": {$exists: true}}},
  {$unset: "userCourses"},
  {$skip: skip},
  {$limit: limit}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kUbI_WASYKN)